# Is there a name for this degenerate kind of monad?

Tags: scala, monads

In Scala monads such as `List`, we have a `map` method that converts a `List[A]` into a `List[B]`, like so:

```
trait List[A] {
  def map[B](f: (A) => B): List[B]
}
```

I have something similar, except the `map` method only takes functions from `A` to `A`, like this:

```
trait State[A] {
  def map(f: (A) => A): State[A]
}
```

Is there a name for a monad with a degenerate `map` method like this? It's not actually a monad any more, is it?

Comment: None that I know of. Do you have an example of such a structure? Note that having just map does not make a monad structure. You need flatMap and a bit more for that. If you have just map (the generic one), satisfying the proper laws, this is just a Functor structure.

Comment: thanks @DidierDupont. no flatmap, so I guess it's just a functor. But I gues it's still a degenerate functor, according to Aleksey's answer below.

Comment: Indeed, definitely not a functor. A functor needs the generic map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type looks like a Functor - let's check if it is.

Searching Hoogle for regular Functor type signature (in Haskell: `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`) returns, obviously, the Functor:

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+f+a+-%3E+f+b

`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

However, searching for `(a -> a) -> f a -> f a` does not find anything related:

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+f+a+-%3E+f+a

There are various types of Functors:

http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/functors-and-things-using-scala/index.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor

but none of the named ones really matches your type signature.

Let's check if your Functor satisfies the laws ([ref1](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Functor+Laws.html), [ref2](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor)):

1)

> if we map the id function over a
>   functor, the functor that we get back should be the same as the
>   original functor.

True because the type returned from `id` is the same as original type.

2)

> composing two functions and then mapping the resulting function over a
>   functor should be the same as first mapping one function over the
>   functor and then mapping the other one.

Also satisfied, although restricted to the type of function you can apply on your functor, i.e. only `A => A` and not `A => B`.

To make it a Monad you need to satisfy these laws:

Left Identity, Right Identity, Associativity.

https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws

http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+laws.html